# Open overlay if today is current day

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I'm in the process of making a Christmas calendar, and I have an overlay which should open if the date is ex 1.12.13, otherwise it should alert the amount of days until it's available. I've tried a lot of different things but can't get it to work.

Here is what should be displayed if date is something:

```
       <!-- overlayed element, which is styled with external stylesheet -->
       <div class="apple_overlay black" id="photo1">
       <img src="images/onecom.png" alt="onecom" width="496" height="496" />
       <div class="details">
        <h2>December 1st</h2>
         <p>
          Some script that does something
         </p>
        </div>
        </div>
```

What I have tried

```
function dooropen(door) {
    today=new Date(); 
    daynow=today.getDate(); 
    monthnow=today.getMonth();
    if (monthnow!=11 && monthnow!=0) {
        alert("This feature opens in December. Please come back then."); 
        return false;
    } 
    if (daynow==door-1) {
        alert("Come back tomorrow to see what's behind that door!");
        return false;
    }
    if (door>daynow) {
        alert("You\'ll have to wait "+(door-daynow)+" days before that door's available!"); 
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried something like this:

Comment: function dooropen(door)
{

today=new Date();
daynow=today.getDate();
monthnow=today.getMonth();if (monthnow!=11 && monthnow!=0) {alert("This feature opens in December. Please come back then."); return false;}
if (daynow==door-1) {alert("Come back tomorrow to see what's behind that door!");return false;}
if (door>daynow) {alert("You\'ll have to wait "+(door-daynow)+" days before that door's available!"); return false;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may work, as i can see you may have some different `div` for each day of the month since you are using numeric id `id="photo1">`, so you can try to get the dates :

```
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate() + 1;
    var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
```

after that get the main parent of all divs and put it in a jquery object:

```
var $number_of_objects = $("#parent_div img");
```

once you have all those you need to put them inside a for loop to count them and match to later exit the function:

```
for (var i = 1; i < $number_of_objects.length; i++) {
    console.log("value of i " + i);
        if(i == dd){
            console.log(' break');
            break;
        }
        $("#apple img[rel='#photo"+i+"']").overlay({
                effect: 'apple'
        });

    }
```

it should give you a good start point to improve it and add more feature to the script :) 
happy coding

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    var date = new Date(),
    year = date.getYear(),
    month = date.getMonth()+1,
    day = date.getDate();

    if(day == 13){ // today is 13
       code
    }else{
       code
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just show the element you want at the end of your method..

```
$('#photo1').show();
```